# Use JOIN on same table having a date partition for a date range in Hive/mysql

Tags: mysql, hadoop, join, hive, left-join

I have looked for this problem but I have not been able to find a similar issue involving date partition which is where I am stuck.

So I have a table with columns campaign_id, user_id, impression_count, click_count with day, month and year as partitions. Now I need to find the campaigns which were live yesterday and then aggregate data for the last 30 days for those campaigns. What I basically want to find is the number of times an impression for the same campaign is being shown to an user.

This is the query I wrote to get the data for 1 day:

```
SELECT result.impressions, result.campaign, result.clicks, count(result.user_id) as FREQ 
FROM
    (SELECT campaign_id as campaign, user_id, sum(impression_count) as impressions, sum(click_count) as clicks 
      from table 
        where properties_day={day} 
          AND properties_month={month} 
          AND properties_year={year} 
      group by campaign_id, user_id)AS result 
GROUP BY campaign, impressions, clicks;
```

Now I have been trying to do this for the last 30 days but this is as far as I have been able to get. I am not sure how to use JOIN and at the same time use a WHERE condition such Date_Table2 = Date_Table1 - 30 days.

```
SELECT T1.campaign_id, T1.user_id, T1.sum(impression_count),T1.sum(click_count),
T2.campaign_id, T2.user_id, T2.sum(impression_count), T2.sum(click_count)
FROM Table as T1 
LEFT JOIN Table as T2
 ON T1.campaign_id = T2.campaign_id
  AND T1.user_id=T2.user_id
WHERE T1.properties_day={day} 
  AND T1.properties_month={month} 
  AND T1.properties_year={year}
  AND T2.properties_day BETWEEN T1.properties_day - 30 AND T1.properties_et_day - 1
  AND T2.properties_month<=T1.properties_month
  AND T2.properties_year   T1.properties_year
group by T1.campaign_id, T1.user_id)AS test
```

Here is the sample data:

```
   User_ID   |  Campaign_ID | Impression_count  |   Click_count  
   820103109 |     123      |       1           |         0  
   837216609 |     123      |       1           |         1  
   820103109 |     456      |       0           |         0  
   870609097 |     456      |       1           |         1  
   853977465 |     456      |       1           |         0  
   842493228 |     456      |       1           |         1
```

This is what I want my final output to be:

```
Campaign_ID  Frequency Impressions Clicks
  123           0          456       0
  123           1          7382     281
  123           2          2531     172  and so on...
```

I am a beginner to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Visit this page http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @justanothernewbie You have provided your expected result. But the sample data is missing.

Comment: The result set doesn't correspond to the data set

Comment: @Strawberry: the result does correspond to the data set. I am not sure what is it that you think might be an issue. If you can point it out, maybe I can explain it. I had written a query for 1 day which is the 1st query in the question and I got the result in the format above. And I know the result is correct because I have verified it against other datasets.
Update: I realised that you might be confused with the column names in the result. The column frequency in the sample result table is count(user_id)